# Is there something like Turnkey Linux configuration console out there?

Tags: ip, console, display-manager

Turnkey Linux comes with this nice blue background console thing that has some basic options like showing the current IP, time, etc. I find its nicer for our system admins (me too) to be greeted with when they are looking for a specific Virtual Machine in a list of 50.  I might send a request 'can you open port X to the outside world on IP xx.xx.xx.xx' and they might not easily know which machine is that one. [image]

Of course I am not specifically interested if whatever you suggest can replicate these features exactly, but something close to this, where at least the IP address can be displayed, maybe the hostname, etc.

If you aren't familiar with Turnkey Linux Console, you only see it in the actual machine. In ssh terminal sessions, the normal login prompt is displayed.  You can also use the advanced menu to get to the terminal on the actual machine if you must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want this information printed nicely on the console? This solution isn't a curses-based text-GUI like you've shown (with the colored background and dialog box), but has the advantage of working on pretty much any Linux distro: modify `/etc/issue` to present the information you need. On Fedora and other Red Hat family distributions, that file as presented by `agetty` — on other distros, different getty programs may be used but the concept is basically the same. The various getty programs recognize different escape sequences: special codes which are filled in with information at runtime. On Fedora, `/etc/issue` looks like this:

```
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)
```

where `\r` is the kernel release number, `\m` is the machine architecture, and `\l` is the number of the tty (l for "line", presumably). You can find these documented with `man agetty`.

It sounds like you may be interested in `\4`, to show the IPv4 address of the first configured and up interface, or `\n` to show the hostname ("node name") as configured locally (or `\O` for the DNS name).

You can get fancy with colors, too, via sequences like `\e{green}This will be in green\e{reset}` or even `\S{ANSI_COLOR}\S{PRETTY_NAME}\e{reset}`, which will show the operating system name and version in a human-readable way in the color defined as the right one for that OS as defined in `/etc/os-release`. (Like, blue for Fedora and red for RHEL.)

If the available sequences aren't sufficient, you could of course generated the file entirely with some script at boot time.

> If you aren't familiar with Turnkey Linux Console, you only see it in the actual machine. In ssh terminal sessions, the normal login prompt is displayed. You can also use the advanced menu to get to the terminal on the actual machine if you must.

By default, this is only shown on actual consoles — either the physical machine or on the console of VMs. You can configure SSH to do something similar with the `Banner` directive in `sshd_config`, but note that it doesn't support these fancy escape sequences.

Comment: I simply wrote a shell script that is called from rc.local that generates a file and replaces /etc/issue.  My use case is a virtualbox default template image set for dhcp so i can see its ip to ssh to without having to log into it first via the "console"

Answer (score 0):

If your systems are running `network-manager` you can take a look at `nmtui`. On RedHat derivatives, package's name is `NetworkManager-tui`.

It's not directly the thing you want, but you can give it a try. Also you can cook up something with [`dialog`](http://www.unixcl.com/2009/12/linux-dialog-utility-short-tutorial.html) or `ncurses`.

Answer (score 0):

Confconsole (the screenshot you show) is free open source software and is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/turnkeylinux/confconsole).

As TurnKey is Debian based, that's what it's built for. However, it's written in Python so with some tweaking should be able to run anywhere.

Having said that, it sounds like you are only after the basic data supplied on the default page (as per screenshot). If so, you could probably just pull out the relevant code from confconsole if you wished.

Although TBH, if that's all you need, it'd probably be easiest to just write something simple for scratch - as per @mattdm answer.